# Nested vector in PDA account not being properly serialized

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda, vec

I am creating a PDA account that stores a string and a vector. Inside this vector, there is another vector. This is the structure of my account:

```
#[account]
pub struct Monster {
    
    pub seed : String,
    pub evolutions: Vec<Evolution>,
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Evolution {

    pub possible_evolution: String,
    pub requirements: Vec<Requirement>,

}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Requirement {

    pub key_requirement: String,
    pub value_requirement: i16,

}
```

But when i output my code after run anchor test, it show something like this. It seems that the second vector has not been properly serialized:

```
{
  seed: 'ramdomName',
  evolutions: [
    { possibleEvolution: 'evolution1', requirements: [Array] },
    { possibleEvolution: 'evolution2', requirements: [Array] }
  ]
}
```

What could be the problem?

I'm passing the data in my test in this way:

```
    const evolutions = [
      { possibleEvolution: 'evolution1', 
        requirements:[
          {keyRequirement:'gender', valueRequirement: 100},
          {keyRequirement:'attack', valueRequirement:200}
        ] 
      },

      { possibleEvolution: 'evolution2', 
        requirements:[
          {keyRequirement:'gender', valueRequirement:100},
        ]
      },
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine. My bad. I used the JSON.stringify method in my test to convert the account object to a string with 2 spaces of indentation for each level of nesting, and that way it was displayed properly.